# how does this data structure work?

Tags: perl

I have to some debugging on an existing script without having a lot of knowledge about perl.

This script uses data types like these to store all the fields from a file:

```
${$LineRefs->{FIELD_NAME}}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to find all possible fields separately by iterating over this scalar/hash/array or whatever it may be but I have no clue how.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I can point you in this direction: http://perldoc.perl.org/ is a comprehensive documentation site for Perl. Specifically, you want to read about data structures: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: What is your sample statement `${$LineRefs->{FIELD_NAME}}` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly very odd

`$LineRefs` is a reference to a hash which has an element with key `FIELD_NAME` whose value is a *reference* to a scalar

Like this

```
use v5.14;

my $LineRefs = {
    FIELD_NAME => \99,
};

print ${ $LineRefs->{FIELD_NAME} }, "\n";
```

#### output

```
99
```

References to hashes and arrays are common because they allow a large data structure to be represented by a single scalar. But references to scalars are far less useful because they just replace a scalar by another scalar

---

I'm sorry, thanks [**@glennjackman**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134357/how-does-this-data-structure-work/35134748#comment57989445_35134748) I read the question too hastily and assumed it was about why a hash element was being dereferenced as a scalar

> I've been trying to figure out how to find all possible fields separately by iterating over this scalar/hash/array or whatever it may be but I have no clue how

You're dealing with a *hash*, which is like an array but indexed by strings (keys) instead of integers (indexes)

You can use [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html), or [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) to iterate over a hash

You can print all the keys and their values like this. Since your variable `$LineRefs` is a *hash reference* you need to *dereference* it as `%$LineRefs`

```
for my $key ( keys %$LineRefs ) {
    my $value = $LineRefs->{$key};
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

If your hash values really are references to scalars then you will see things like `SCALAR(0x640448)` printed for the values

Comment: And you can find all the fields with `keys %$LineRefs` -- `say for keys %$LineRefs;`

Comment: A module of great help for such things is [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).
It's used to dump perl structures in a readable form, no matter how complicated they are.
It's part of the core distribution. Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($my_strucutre);`.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks Glenn. I overlooked the intent of the question and focussed on the oddity of having scalar references as values

Comment: many thanks, `keys %$LineRefs` returned exactly what I needed